# Get value from another site (yahoo)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

there is a wayto get the value from yahoo site in this url "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=mo&ql=1". i need only the value of "Next Earnings Date".
how to do that in ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Since Cross-Domain-Requests are not allowed in Browsers, you can't do it with pure JavaScript. You can either use php with curl to fetch the page and parse it, or use a helper API.

I would recommend having a look at YQL (Yahoo Query Language). With this API you can fetch any page.

https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

A jQuery plugin that makes use of this API is: https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax